# When you're handling events from many users is there a way to differentiate yourself from others

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

When you're handling events from many users is there a way to differentiate yourself from others. In other words, is there a way to interrogate (I guess thru sender or Event Args) who's request is being handled?

Maybe get an ip address, or other meta data about the observer?

```
_x.HeySomethingChanged += async (s, e) =>
    {
        SetPageState();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    };
```

Comment: If I understand your problem. you could get Ip Address of each request of users, if your users not authenticated. then store it on cache and check in each next request!

Comment: The question is unclear because event handlers always run in a single user's context and session

Answer (score 1):

IP address is not a unique data for example in a LAN behind router.

Assuming this page is a public page, my solution would be to hold an ID or GUID to recognize the current user. For WASM Blazor
one option is to hold in the [fluxor](https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor) state after first page loaded.

For Server side Blazor hold in session or local storage.